Return something from onclick?
I have a function that creates a chart with pandas & matplotlib. In the function there is an onclick handler that creates a table and then shows it with plt.show() upon click.
When the entire function ends with plt.show(), the chart displays and onclick works. But if I change the code to return an encoded binary of the fig object, then send it to a UI, onclick does not work.
How can I get onclick to work when I return the encoded binary of the fig?
def create_chart():
    # other code
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data = {"A": A, "B": B, "C": C},
        index=D,
    )

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    legend_elements = [...]
    ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc="best")

    # Line
    ax.plot(df["A"], marker="o",color='DodgerBlue',linewidth=4.5,markersize=6)

    plt.tight_layout(rect=(-.05, 0, 1, 1))
    fig.set_size_inches(get_chart_size(B),4.8)

    # Experiment with onclick
    def onclick(event):
        """ onclick """
        if event.inaxes:
            # Create a new figure for the table
            table_ax = plt.subplots()
            table_ax.axis('off')
            table = table_ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
            table.auto_set_font_size(False)
            table.set_fontsize(10)
            table.scale(1.2, 1.2)
            plt.show()            # should I return something here?

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    # plt.show()                 # onclick works locally if i do this as the end of function
    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
    buf.seek(0)

    # Encode the image as base64
    img = base64.b64encode(buf.read()).decode("ascii")
    return img


"to return an encoded binary of the fig object, then send it to a UI". pyplot does not have control of the image anymore, it's that UI the one to handle the event.

@LMC hm yea that would make sense
